# Execute many process concurently nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have a problem about executing query concurently in Nodejs.
First I read all data from mysql, it's about 5000 records. Then check all these records in Mongo then update back to mysql.
What way is the best? I 'm thinking about using async module to execute limit of record first, then keep going. is it ok?
Something like :

```
async.whilst(
    function() {return ..;},
    function(callbackOut) {
       record1,record2,record3
       async.parallel([
          function(record1),function(record2),function(record3) 
       ]),
       function() {
           callbackOut();
       } ..
  }
```

Edit: I have just checked async.eachLimit (by freele's suggestion) and it's better than combine whilst and parallel. But is it another way better ? like fork new childprocess or ..?

Comment: You can use async if you're working with callbacks or Q if you prefer promises. I don't think you need `whilst`, as I see you should use `each` (or eachLimit if you need limit). Or `async.parallel([
    function(){ ... },
    function(){ ... }
], callback);` should be enough. What are you going to return in your first function?

Comment: i will return the id of each record in mongo. I will push it in to an array when function in parallel done and it 's not a problem. I just don't know what to fill in "[ function(){ ... }, function(){ ... } ]" because it is just a function with many value.

Comment: each function is a function of a kind `function(object, done){..}` Where done() called after finishing async stuff with the object.

Comment: year, i think eachLimit fit with my case, not parallel. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [parallelLimit](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallellimittasks-limit-callback) to limit the number of concurrent operations to something more small than that 5000, and see if your problem persist

Comment: I have one task with 5000 value to execute.If i only use parallelLimit , I have to make a "tasks" with 5000 function inside. It will ok if i combine whilst and parallel. I just wonder, is it good way? or can do other way like fork process or something ..